# PyQt5 isn't uderstood from VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt5

I have an issue with `PyQt5` and VS Code. I have installed `PyQt5` on my computer but when I write from VS Code it doesn't work. VS Code underlines my imports with a yellow line and when I run the code it says

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.
```

However, when I run the same program from my terminal, it runs fine.  My code is

```py
import sys
 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget,QStackedWidget




class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        loadUi("window.ui",self)

app= QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
widget = QStackedWidget()

widget.addWidget(window)
widget.setFixedHeight(800)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Comment: VS Code doesn't execute your code. Python does. Are you sure you're using the same virtual environment in both cases? Did you install `PyQt5` in a different environment perhaps? If you install something in the global environment it won't appear in virtual environments

Comment: Sounds like you have two versions of python installed on your computer.  The pyqt package is installed for one of them, but not the other.  Update your vs code configuration to use the correct python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be more than one python version installed on your computer, please select the correct python interpreter using:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> command to open the Command Palette
2. search for and select **Python:Select Interpreter**

   *(Or click directly on the **python version** displayed in the lower right corner)*
3. select the correct interpreter.

[image]